# What is the second parameter in this Blobstore blob creation code?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

This is a snippet from the 'Writing Files to the Blobstore' code sample in the [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore):

```
# Open the file and write to it
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write('data')
```

Could you please tell me what the 'a' parameter is for, and why it is necessary? I don't see it referred to anywhere else.

One might assume that it is the file name, but if so, GAE immediately forgets the name and the files are all called 'unnamed' in the GAE backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'a'` specifies that the file be opened for **appending**. It must be specified since the default is `'r'`: read mode.

It is described thusly in the excellent Python documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> The most commonly-used values of mode are `'r'` for reading, `'w'` for
>   writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and `'a'` for
>   appending...

Comment: Thanks, bernie. Silly of me not to have searched the Python docs. I just assumed it was some GAE-specific code. As you can tell, I'm new to Python.

Comment: You're most welcome. It's a perfectly reasonable assumption to make, and indeed one of the reasons sites like this exist is to assist with those initial steps when everything is new and mistakes are very easy to make. Cheers, and best of luck on your project.